# Correct way to add controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, control-array

```
CheckBox[] checkBoxArray = new CheckBox[lines.Count()];
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

int yLocation = 25;
int diff = 0;
int i = 0;
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    this.checkBox.Text = line;
    this.checkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, yLocation + diff);
    this.checkBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 30);
    checkBoxArray[i] = checkBox;
    i++;
    diff = diff + 30;
}
```

I debugged my app and `checkBoxArray` (after the loop) is all the same.

The second issue is how do I add my controls to the WinForm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're actually working with some class-level member called checkBox instead of the locally-scoped one:

```
CheckBox[] checkBoxArray = new CheckBox[lines.Count()];

int yLocation = 25;
int diff = 0;
int i = 0;
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.Text = line;
    checkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, yLocation + diff);
    checkBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 30);
    checkBoxArray[i] = checkBox;
    i++;
    diff = diff + 30;
    Controls.Add(checkBox);  // Add checkbox to form
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `checkBoxArray` is, but if it was just an attempt to get things working, you can safely get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't create a new `CheckBox` instance inside the loop, then you're just overwriting the values on the same `CheckBox` again and again.

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // Create a new CheckBox
    var checkBox = new CheckBox();

    // Set its properties
    checkBox.Text = line;
    ...

    // Add it to the form's collection of controls
    this.Controls.Add(checkBox);

    // Adjust checkBox.Location depending on where you want it
    checkBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you a bit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266

```
this.Controls.Add(checkBox);
```

Comment: why not add the CheckBoxArray? how about the first issue where all the data is the same.

Comment: This is *part* of the answer only.